# How do I get this div to show up above the top div

Tags: html, z-index

my firt post here , so please guide me with any errors I make and general culture with these forums.

please see below.

http://jsfiddle.net/LGTp7/

```
<body>
    <div class="red">

    </div>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="planner-table green">
            <div class="planner-row">
                <div class="planner-cell">
                    <div class="black"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="planner-row">
                <div class="planner-cell">
                    <div class="blue"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Please see attached fiddle .

This is a simple representation of the layout of a legacy project , the `blue square` represent a bootstrap `datetimepicker` that has been implemented.

how ever when it is selected , it ends up hiding the top part of the picker behind the top `"RED" div`.

the `date pickers Z-index is "9999 !important"` in the css. How do I get the `blue box` (date picker representation) to show above the `red div` (top div).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of `overflow-y: auto` on the `.outer` element, combined with `position: relative`. The blue box gets cut off, because it goes out of the container. Vertical overflow needs to be `visible` on it to make this work.

Now you certainly need the `position: relative`, and I guess you need the overflow too. The solution is to put them on different elements, instead of one. `position: relative` should be outside.

One possible way is to put the overflow on `.planner-table-green`, so you can keep everything you need and it will still work:

```
.outer{
    position:relative;
}

.planner-table-green {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

- [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LGTp7/1/)
- [CSS Tricks article about the phenomenon](http://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/)

Nothing to do with `z-index`, you do not need it here, the natural order should be fine.

<sub>I found the problem using the inspector of my web browser, systematically disabling CSS properties.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
.outer {
   overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The blue will only stay within the parent divs that it follows. You would have to change the position to fixed if you want it to ignore any of it's branches. The red is in a div separate from the outer div, which is why you can not move it up.